# python code does not give the right results/ production optimization

Tags: python, loops

i am very new to programming and this is my first code. The goal of this code is to tell me on which machine i should produce which job to not be tardy.

The programm works, but i dont get the right results.
In this particular case i have 30 jobs and 3 machines. If i run the code it gives out 3 tardy jobs as the result.
When i reproduce the case on a sheet of paper, i only get 2 tardy jobs as the result.

I dont know why the code stops to early in case of distribution.

The problem might be in the loop (if else) but i dont know how to fix it.

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me!

Thanks in advance!

```
import random
random.seed(1)

number_of_jobs = 30 
number_of_machines = 3 

class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, duration, duedate, done):
        self.duration = duration
        self.duedate = random.randint(12,22)
        self.done = done

all_jobs = [] #Liste aller Jobs
for i in range(number_of_jobs): 
    all_jobs.append(Job(random.randint(1,3),{},False))
all_jobs.sort(key = lambda x: x.duedate, reverse = False)

print("\nAusgangssituation: \n") 

for job in all_jobs: 
    print(job.duration, job.duedate, job.done)

class Machine(object):
    def __init__(self, workload): 
        self.workload = workload

print("") 

all_machines =[] #Liste aller Maschinen
for i in range(number_of_machines):
    all_machines.append(Machine(0)) 

for machine in all_machines: 
    print(machine.workload)



iterations = 0 

for job in all_jobs:
    while iterations < number_of_machines:
        if job.duration + all_machines[iterations].workload <= job.duedate:
            job.done = True 
            all_machines[iterations].workload = all_machines[iterations].workload + job.duration 
            iterations = 0
            all_machines.sort(key = lambda x: x.workload, reverse = False)
            break
        else:
            iterations = iterations + 1
            continue



print("\nErgebnis: \n") 

for job in all_jobs: 
    print(job.duration, job.duedate, job.done)

print("") 

for machine in all_machines: 
    print(machine.workload)

possible_jobs = sum(job.done == True for job in all_jobs)
print("\nDie Anzahl der pünktlichen Jobs ist:",possible_jobs,"\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `iterations = 0` should be inside of for-loop like this

```
for job in all_jobs:
    iterations = 0  # <<<<<
    while iterations < number_of_machines:
        if job.duration + all_machines[iterations].workload <= job.duedate:
            job.done = True 
            all_machines[iterations].workload = all_machines[iterations].workload + job.duration 
            iterations = 0
            all_machines.sort(key = lambda x: x.workload, reverse = False)
            break
        else:
            iterations = iterations + 1
            continue
```

what you need is initializing `iterations` to 0 for every for-loop.